# Bootstrap container width change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for my website and I need to create a container with size of 1250px, but the problem is when I change the class of Bootstrap container the responsiveness won't work anymore.

What should I do?

Answer (score 14):

Just setting 'container-fluid' will create a 100% width container. Wrapping the whole thing in a 1250px width container will cause your container not to be responsive. The best thing to do is to assign a 'max-width' to your fluid container, I've included the markup below:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#CDCDCD; max-width:1250px">
```

Container-Fluid

Answer (score 11):

You can create a custom container and use it with default container (just overwriting the width). you can change the width according to your need:

CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:600px;
}}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:720px;
}}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.my-custom-container{
    width:900px;
}}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container my-custom-container">
your content Goes here .......
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give width to container in your css file:

```
.container {
    width:1250px;
}
```

Then write media query for making it responsive:

```
@media only screen and
(max-width : 1249px ) {

    .container {
        width:100%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the width of container as you like. For this please add these css lines:

```
.container{ 
  max-width:1250px; 
  width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try fluid container for bootstrap ?

Try change 'container' to the 'container-fluid'

It may be help

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of container as you like.For this please add these css lines

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1250px !important;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put a special class like `my_custom_menu` to your menu container. then copy this style below to your stylesheet....

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container.my_custom_menu  {
    width: 1250px;
  }
}
```

Thank You